# UFW insert [number] throws error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ufw

Using Ubuntu server 14.04LTS I want to configure my UFW to limit ssh connections with the following command:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 limit ssh/tcp
```

which throws an error: `ERROR: Invalid position '1'`

Due to the fact that this command accepts no number at all there should be no other rule placed under number 1...

```
man ufw
```

outputs the following `insert NUM RULE` whereas `RULE` should be `limit ssh/tcp`. That said my syntax should be correct.

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Answer (score 4):

This is because `position '1'` can only be valid if there is already existing at least a rule, so to insert your rule in position 1 you just need to insert a rule without position at all it will be default to `position '1'` from then on you can have `position '2'` or `position '3'`

Comment: I don't see it. I have same ipv6 rules added. And without controlling position they are not working, because rules before allows ports.